# What is the FRB's Z.1 table L.218

Tags: debt, federal-reserve, securities

I'm updating a document that cites this:

> As of December 2011, 67 percent of home mortgage debt was either
>   securitized through agency or non-agency MBS or held on the balance sheets
>   of Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac (source: Federal Reserve Statistical Release >Z.1, “Flow of Funds Accounts of the United States,” Table L.218).

So I've looked at most recent Table L.218 and I'm trying to extract the relevant data to get the percentage as of Mar. 2016.  But I want to be sure I understand what the table represents.  Does it show who holds all the mortgage debt in the US?

And does the data cited in the quote above come from rows 18, 19, and 20?
Here's the data:  https://www.federalreserve.gov/RELEASES/z1/current/z1r-4.pdf